# Is there a way to create a source distribution incl. subpackages without __init__.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

Is it possible to create a source distribution with `python setup.py sdist` without having to use some sort of `__init__.py` files in every (sub)package (python 3.5+)? I really would like to just use namespace packages to avoid any redundancy and overhead. All nested `.py`-files in all subpackages should be included.

So take the following project structure (I tried to be analogous to [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html)):

[image: project_structure]

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    version="0.0.1",
    name="py_import_test",
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    packages=find_packages(where='src')
)
```

In `main.py` I use something like

```
import py_import_test.p1.helloworld
# do something with helloworld-module
```

When I `python setup.py sdist` with the above project structure, I get no source files at all in the resulting .tar.gz. It only works, if there is `__init__.py` under `py_import_test`, `p1` and possible further subpackages.

All in all, my goal is to have some standalone application package, that I can use to test against and easily install my package to a remote server. For this purpose, I would like to have the source tree as lean as possible and utilize up-to-date python packaging patterns.

Apart from my question regarding `__init__.py` : Would the procedure above be considered a good/modern practise?

Greetings

Comment: Just put the `__init__.py` files into the directories and they will magically become packages. Don't worry, they do not byte!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `find_packages`, you want [`find_namespace_packages`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#find-namespace-packages) (previously known as `find_packages_ns`).

A recent version of setuptools is required; the function was added in [version 40.1.0](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v40-1-0), released in August 2018.

You also need to be careful that you don't include directories that aren't intended to be packages, but the `where='src'` that you already have should take care of that.

Comment: thanks, works like a charm. I had to `pip install setuptools --upgrade` before.